# Convert base 10 and base 255 integer strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, biginteger, bignum

Does anyone know a way to convert base 10 and base 255 strings in JavaScript exceeding the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` value without using a big number library?

For something like:

```
var base10 = '23456786543234567876543234567876543267';
var base255 = base10ToBase255(base10);
```

To base-255 or from base-255 as:

```
var base255 = new Uint8Array(20);
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) base255[i] = 254 - i;
var base10 = base255ToBase10(base255);
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean base 255? Isn't that base 256? In your loop, you use value 255, which would not be possible in base 255 (as it uses values from 0 to 254)...

Comment: @PaulS. There's something not right with your logic. One base-510 digit represents a value from 0 to 509, not 0 to 10^51-1.

Comment: …Also, come to think of it, a pair of base-255 digits would be equivalent to one digit in base-65025 (255*255), not base-510. (Just as two base-10 digits are equivalent to one digit in base-100, not base-20!)

Comment: @duskwuff you are totally right, I don't know what I was thinking D:

Comment: @jcaron yes I'm thinking base-255.  The objective is to convert biginteger.js values from strings to byte arrays for compact storage - I can get away with calling the first byte the sign but need to save a character for a decimal point (treating both the integer and the fractional portion as integers so there are no rounding errors from the base conversion within the limits of the precision being used.)  The range would be 0-254

Comment: So you have decimals (from a big-integer library?) and want to safe them as [sign,decimalpos,numberarray]? If you got them from a big number erlibrray, why don't you take that number directly? It is most probably stored as f*2^e where the fraction part is a big integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**: changed to allow for other bases (<=256)
It always boils down to using a big integer, sorry. But you do not need much, it's just about 100 lines of code for what you want (string to base 256 and back).

```
"use strict";
var COMMON_BASE = 255; // must be 256 at most!
function copyA(a){
    var ret = new Uint8Array(a.length);
    for(var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
        ret[i] = a[i];
    }
    return ret;
}

function isZero(a){
    for(var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i] !== 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function clampA(a){
    var alen = a.length;
    var i=0;
    while(a[alen - 1] === 0)alen--;
    var ret = new Uint8Array(alen);
    for(var i = 0;i<alen;i++){
        ret[i] = a[i];
    }
    return ret;
}


function addD(a,d) {
    var tlen = a.length;
    var carry = 0;
    var ret = new Uint8Array(tlen +1);
    if(d === 0)
        return copyA(a);
    var i = 0;
    var temp = carry;
    temp += a[i] + d;
    carry = Math.floor(temp / COMMON_BASE);
    ret[i] = temp % COMMON_BASE;
    for (i = 1; i < tlen; i++) {
        temp = carry;
        temp += a[i];
        carry = Math.floor(temp / COMMON_BASE);
        ret[i] = temp % COMMON_BASE;
    }
    if (carry) {
        ret[i] = carry;
    }

    ret = clampA(ret);
    return ret;
};

function mulD(a,d){
    var tlen = a.length;
    var carry = 0;
    var ret = new Uint8Array(tlen + 1);
    var k = 0;
    var tmp;
    if(isZero(a))
        return copyA(a);
    if(d === 0)
        return new Uint8Array(tlen);
    for (; k < tlen; k++) {
        tmp = a[k] * d + carry;
        ret[k] = tmp % COMMON_BASE;
        carry = Math.floor(tmp / COMMON_BASE);
    }
    if (carry) {
        ret[k] = carry;
    }
    ret = clampA(ret);
    return ret;
}

function divRem(a,d){
      var divrem = function(u, m, v, q, B) {
        var k = 0,
            t;
        for (var j = m - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            k = (k * COMMON_BASE) ;
            k += u[j];
            if (k >= v) {
                t = Math.floor(k / v);
                k -= t * v;
            } else {
                t = 0;
            }
            q[j] = t;
        }
        return k;
    };
    var Q = new Uint8Array(a.length);
    var R = divrem(a,a.length, d, Q, 8);
    Q = clampA(Q);
    return [Q,R];
}

// Assuming 's' being a string with decimal digits
function base10ToBase256(s){
  var blen = 0;
  // checks&balances omitted
  var out = new Uint8Array(1);
  for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    out = mulD(out,10);
    out = addD(out,parseInt(s[i],10) );
  }
  return out;
}
// Assuming b being a Uint8Array
function base256ToBase10(a){
  var s = "";
  var t = copyA(a);
  var qr = [];
  var i = a.length;
  while(!isZero(t)){
    qr = divRem(t,10);
    s = s + qr[1].toString(10);
    t = qr[0];
  }
  return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

var str = "8716418673416734167345634096788356249857";
//base10ToBase256(str).join(",");
base256ToBase10(base10ToBase256(str));



var str = "8716418673416734167345634096788356249857";
console.log(base10ToBase256(str).join(","));
console.log(base256ToBase10(base10ToBase256(str)));
```

Here the LSB is at position zero.
It's a rough hack (way too much copies etc.) but it'll do it.

Comment: Thanks, using your example I was able to modify it to support base-255 (sorry if my question wasn't clear at first, in the pseudo-code I had made the mistake of doing `255 - i` instead of `254 - i`.)  A version with both 255 and 256 bases supported is located at https://jsfiddle.net/28nvLaL5/2/ - thank you for your help with this :)

Comment: You just changed the names of the functions in your jsfiddle, not the base. It is still base-256.

Comment: I missed something somewhere and having trouble finding it - any idea where it is? https://jsfiddle.net/28nvLaL5/4/ I suspect it's related to the mask in the mulD function but tried swapping between 254 and 127 to account for endianess but that didn't get it unless it is utilized elsewhere too.

Comment: thanks again for your help - if you want it there's a more OO version in the latest version of that fiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/28nvLaL5/18/

Comment: The mask is always `base - 1`. Endinaness shouldn't be a problem, you can check for it and act accordingly but you need a BOM somehwere if you want it portable between different endianesses.